# Call a function inside $('document').ready

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax

I have a function defined inside a `$('document').ready`.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  function visit(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      container: '#maincontainer',
      success: function(data) {
        init();
      }
    });
  }

  function init() {
    ...
  }
)};
```

But when I call `init()` in Chrome Console I get : `ReferenceError: init is not defined`.

**Update:** Thank you all for your help. I did`window.init = init;` and it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't understand the sense of defining a (non-anonimous) function inside the ready method. Just declare them outside and then call it when and where you need.

Comment: [That should work](http://jsfiddle.net/4pZ5J/). Are you sure it's not `var a = function init() { }`? Also, your code example should end with `})`, **not** `)}`.

Comment: This *shouldn't* work. The Chrome Inspector console has no access to the state within an anonymous closure.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: There are *lots* of reasons for creating named functions within the `ready`. Chief amongst them is if the rest of your code is only going to be used once the DOM is ready, it's a handy scoping container.

Comment: I forgot to read the last sentence. I shall go back to work now... :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `init` function is contained by the scope of the function you've passed to `jQuery.ready`. This is a **good thing**, it means you haven't created an unnecessary global.

If you need to export the function to the global scope, you can do so by explicitly assigning to a property on `window`, e.g.:

```
window.init = init;
```

Since `window` is the [global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1) on browsers, that would allow you to call it from Chrome's console without the `window.` prefix. But only do that if absolutely necessary, the global scope is already crowded enough.

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations, like your `function init() {}`, are restricted to the scope they're defined in. If you want to use init elsewhere, do this:

```
var init;
$('document').ready(function() {
    init = function() {};
});
```

Comment: That doesn't apply here. That anonymous function has access to its parent's scope, and hoisting makes `init` available from the start of the scope.

Comment: @alex: Really? I just tested defining a function within another function, and it wasn't available outside the closure.

Comment: The OP's `init` function is defined within the DOM ready callback.

Comment: @alex: Huh? A function being anonymous has no effect on the scope it has access to, that depends entirely on where (named or not) the function is defined. Unless Twisol has modified the answer since you made that comment...? In Twisol's answer, there's a global-scope variable which is being initialized by the code within the `ready` function.

Comment: @alex: Then he calls it from the Chrome inspector, which is not within the context of the DOM ready callback.

Comment: @Twisol: Yeah, I didn't think so. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Forgive me, it is Monday morning here. But I am looking at `init` and `visit` defined within the DOM ready callback, and a callback of `visit` is calling `init`, i.e. simplified [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pRrMv/). In which case, the OP's code should work and not have to rely on Twisol's workaround. Have I missed something?

Comment: @alex: Yes, you've missed where the OP said *"But when I call `init()` in Chrome Console..."* :-) Calls from the console are from global scope, not inside `ready`.

Comment: @T.J. I seem to be forgetting to read the entire question. Carry on chaps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var objScope = this;

  function visit(url) {
    $.pjax({
      url: url,
      container: '#maincontainer',
      success: function(data) {
        objScope.init();
      }
    });
  }

  function init() {
    ...
  }
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put your function definition outside the ready function, it is not necessary for the document to be ready to define a function even if the function references the document. Keep in mine the references inside a function are not performed until the function is actually executed, a function definition is just like defining a text constant. Use the following instead:

```
function visit(url) {
    $.pjax({
        url: url,
        container: '#maincontainer',
        success: function(data) {
        init();
        }
    });
}

function init() {
    ...
}

$(function () {
    init();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Functions are only defined the scope you define them in.

If you insist on this method, use `init = funciton()` syntax instead. This will create a global variable (since you're not going to put a `var` there) which can be referenced anywhere.

That said, defining functions can be done at any time, there is absolutely no point in putting them in `.ready()`.

Comment: *"If you insist on this method, use init = funciton() syntax instead"* **OMG** that's a bad suggestion. Use `window.init = function...`, perhaps, but **never** rely on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: If you know what you are doing, implicit globals are perfectly acceptable. Most people, however, don't have the foggiest notion what they're doing.

Comment: `@Kolink`: If you know what you're doing, you don't *need* implicit globals. If you don't, they're a trap you're going to trip over.

Comment: True. I never use them myself, to be honest.